# htaccess mod_rewrite, one syntax works, but other no

Tags: php, .htaccess

When I write in .htaccess this mod_rewrite

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^(.*)\.my_extension$ $1.php
```

This wroks fine.

But when I am trying mod_rewrite like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
```

this gives me `Internal Server Error` when open any address, for example `site.com/somepage`

So,  what may be   reason of this?

Comment: The reason is the reason given: An internal server error occured. And that is an invitation to visit the error log. Please consult the documentation of your server-software to find out more.

Comment: your in an infinite loop - always rewriting to index.php

Comment: @Waygood: Now he got that problem. However first problem is to know where to find out. Apache tells this in the error log. Better point there because it is likely the next problem is around the corner (syntax error in regex is common as well).

Comment: i agree (repeating it wouldnt gain anything). Anyone have a  link to how to setup rewrite logs or a mod_rewrite tutorial?

Comment: @hakre I cant see server error log, because its not my own server, I have this on shared hosting.  @Waygood  `your in an infinite loop`  but always rewriting to index.php works in other server, why here not works? reason may be  some option?

Comment: @OTARIKI: Contact your hoster, he is able to point you to the right direction where you can find the servers error log. Otherwise create a testbed that uses the same software and reproduce the problem on your end and if you're not willing to do that, change your hoster. You need access to the servers error log of your virtual host, shared hosting or not.

Comment: @hakre I test `David Houde` code from hes answer and as I see this is  redirect loop problem, now reason I know, but I have other problem, please see My comment in `David's` answer and if you can, tell how to solve problem? ( if this possible of course). Thanks.

Comment: @OTARIKI: Well, he just gave you the answer. This should give you all requests to index.php including the requests to index.php. Don't know what you're puzzled about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(index.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
```

You have a redirect loop, you need to exclude index.php from the rules.

Comment: mmm.... Yes, it seems that this is redirect loop problem. But I need that any url, redirect in to `index.php` file (this need for making one entry point for MVC).  How to solve this? there are some way?

Comment: Yes, please see the answer we are commenting on! Your code is close, but you need the middle line I included...this pretty much says "redirect any url to index.php EXCEPT for index.php" to avoid a loop.

Comment: When I use your code, now server returns error like this: `the requested file index.php not found on this server`